# Is margin/padding acceptable as inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

It's best practise to have all the styling in an external CSS file to take advantage of caching, separation of markup and design, better overview etc.

However, I usually ran into the problem that elements are supposed to look the same, i.e. have the same class(es), but need to differ in position, e.g. require a different margin or padding due to composition differences.

I thought of three options:

**Option 1**: Split appearance styles from position styles (margin/padding), have them in separate classes and combine them as needed.

```
.myClass { ...; }
.myClass.top { margin-top: 20px; }
.myClass.inside { margin: 10px 0px; }
.myClass.bottom { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

**Option 2**: Duplicate classes, rename them accordingly and keep every difference in its own class.

```
.myClassTop { ...; margin-top: 20px; }
.myClass { ...; margin: 10px 0px; }
.myClassBottom { ...; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

**Option 3**: Use inline style to declare different margin/padding.

```
<div class="myClass" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="myClass">
<div class="myClass" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

having

```
.myClass { ...; margin: 10px 0px; }
```

My common sense tells me to use Option 1 and cascade differences depending on the parent/child structure. But this usually ends up pretty confusing, especially for other developers reading the CSS. So I tried Option 3 (having just a few external margin/padding) and that seems to work pretty well.

I still feel bad about it in some strange way. There are so many people telling not use inline style. Usually I'd say "whatever works best", but recently I realized that inline margin/padding might have impact on the rendering process of the website, causing "dancing blocks". I'm not sure if this effect is really caused by the processing order of styles or rather some other nasty things going on there, I guess.

Any advise?

Comment: It depends entirely on your HTML, but if it's the first of the `.myClass` elements that needs to be styled differently you have the option of `div.myClass:first-child` Or, possibly, `h1 + div.myClass` (assuming that it follows a `h1` element, obviously.

Comment: @David Thomas: That sounds like it would be a good answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: the question, as written, can't be answered with any authority (since it's purely speculative, and without a defined use-case). Had there been HTML to see, then I probably would have answered with that (or similar).

Comment: @David Thomas: Hmm, you have a point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My personal preference is to have "spacer classes", so to speak. For example:

```
.default-row-spacer{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.default-spacer{
    margin-right:10px;
}
.large-row-spacer{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Then I use them like this:

```
<div class="panel default-spacer default-row-spacer">
    <div class="content default-row-spacer">
    </div>
    <div class="content default-row-spacer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right-panel default-row-spacer">
</div>
```

This allows me to later change **all** of the site's margins later on, maintaining the same look and feel throughout my website.

Answer (score 2):

it depends very much on your problems,

when you have to do this very very often and the values are not too different or you can closure this to "top 10 margin´s" , it may be usefull to make extra-classes like

```
.tTwenty { margin-top:20px;}
.bTwenty {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

and add them like

```
<div class="myClass tTwenty">
<div class="myClass">
<div class="myClass bTwenty">
```

but all your solutions will work, it´s just a difference of taking care of it
but you should not start using inline-styles because you get laid with them and you start to fix every little stuff with inline-css, and then it gets hairy because when you look at this in a year you have to mix up the extern css and your inlines to understand the styling, and you need to touch every single document with the inline-style instead of fixing everything in your css-files

Comment: Dont call your classes *twenty* *ten* or else, cause one day if you decide 22 is really cool...

Comment: Wish I could upvote your comment more @roXon. Don't name your classes after the properties they contain.

Comment: @Seer not even `.clear-fix`?

Comment: Hmmm, that should have been phrased better. Clearfix is an odd exception, because it's not often you'll want to change the functionality of a clear fixing class. There will be other exceptions too, but, for the majority of the time using something like `.tTwenty` is a bad idea. I'm sure you understand why, and I'm glad you pointed that out about the exceptions.

Comment: ofcourse you are right, feel free to edit, I wrote that  under the condition you have your topTen Margins you could also call the case1 case2 or whatever, anyway the best case is to design stuff better to do uniform classifications

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem I have encountered myself developing an eCommerce site where almost all content was being generated dynamically. Since most content blocks were repeated more than once, I couldn't style them equally since I wanted to style different blocks in different ways - similar to what you are noticing.

What I ended up doing was using Chrome's Inspect Element to find out exactly the hierarchy of div's and classes and ended up doing something like this:

Option 4:

```
.myClass { ...; }
.thumbnail .myClass { margin-top: 20px; }
div.leftCol .myClass { margin: 10px 0px; }
footer .myClass { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

The benefit of this option, in my view, is to not only be able to have all the benefits of your option 1, but you **don't have to add new classes** and your **CSS remains very structured and readable**.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is: if it needs to be done repititively...like a list of something say comments. And each one has body that appears, 40px under the title, use css classes. If its a one time thing. just one object, say...use inline